# Why is enumerateDevices type not inferred in ReactNativeWebrtc?

Tags: react-native, webrtc, react-native-webrtc

I'm writing code for webrtc, and I'm following the manual, but there's something I don't understand.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(data => {
      console.log('enumerateDevices 로그');
      console.log(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Why is the type of result 'data' not inferred in enumerateDevices?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP96M.png)

The reason why this is curious is that the data returned by getUserMedia in the same library is used for data inference.

```
useEffect(() => {
    mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log('getUserMedia 로그');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88Rt.png)

Check the screenshot above

The value returned by getUserStream is inferred to be of type MediaStream.

I'm curious about this, what's the problem? Or is there a good reason? I wonder why

I'm curious about this, what's the problem? Or is there a good reason? I wonder why